# An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, azure-blob-storage

I am currently using Azure Blob Storage on Android Studio. I am unable to loop through a blob container

it tells me

```
08-10 00:37:16.073 8538-8594/com.psv.starvision W/System.err: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
08-10 00:37:16.073 8538-8594/com.psv.starvision W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
08-10 00:37:16.073 8538-8594/com.psv.starvision W/System.err:     at com.psv.starvision.blobHandler.ListImages(blobHandler.java:81)

Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
08-11 14:10:05.011 8877-8925/com.psv.starvision W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:306)
08-11 14:10:05.011 8877-8925/com.psv.starvision W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:177)
08-11 14:10:05.011 8877-8925/com.psv.starvision W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
```

This is ListImages.Class

```
public static String[] ListImages() {
    LinkedList<String> blobNames = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        CloudBlobContainer container = getContainer();
        Log.e( "listimages: ", "container " + container );

        Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = container.listBlobs();
        Log.e( "listimages: ", "blobs " + blobs );

        blobNames = new LinkedList<>();
        for(ListBlobItem blob: blobs) { // the line that hit an error
            blobNames.add(((CloudBlockBlob) blob).getName());
        }

        Log.e("ListImages: ", "size" + blobNames.size() );
        return blobNames.toArray(new String[blobNames.size()]);

    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return blobNames.toArray(new String[blobNames.size()]);
}
```

Any ideas on what's the issue? The container in question is not empty; I am able to log `container` and `blobs`.

please and thank you!!

Comment: The answer of the other SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578118/java-azure-storage-error-enumerating-the-result may helps, which seems to be similar with yours.

Comment: i will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help!

the error for me was in the gradle script

the dependency was set

```
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '1.2.0'
```

when it should've been

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.8.0@aar'
```

Comment: I have used this only compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.8.0@aar' still i am getting the error as "An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details." can you please suggest me any solution?